# Writing query with given very normalized tables- was asked during interview

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, oracle, 3nf

I was asked this question during the interview with one of top IT industries and I had absolutely no clue. Can anyone tell me how? Either Mysql or Oracle is fine but I am providing the example with mysql.

```
CREATE TABLE employee (employee_ID VARCHAR(5), manager_ID VARCHAR(5));

CREATE TABLE meeting (meeting_ID VARCHAR(1), meeting_title VARCHAR(100));

CREATE TABLE attendee (meeting_ID VARCHAR(1), employee_ID VARCHAR(5));
```

The relationship is pretty straight forward with the example. I think this is a pretty much normalized example up to 3rd normal form. Attendee associates the meeting and participating employee including employees and managers.

The question was to **write a query that finds out the meetings which both employee and his  manager are attending**.

Comment: Maybe it was a test to see if you commented on their completely insane choice of data types for the ID columns.

Comment: Although i agree, I've seen stuff like this in real life, sadly.

Comment: I wonder how many meetings they are expecting to hold, ever. Mind you, if CHAR length semantics is being used, a VARCHAR2(1) could store up to 4,294,967,296 different values, I think.

Answer (score 2):

Something like this would work:

```
SELECT m.*
FROM meeting m 
INNER JOIN attendee a a.meeting_ID = m.meeting_ID
INNER JOIN employee e ON e.employee_ID = a.employee_ID
WHERE (a.meeting_ID,e.manager_ID) IN (SELECT meeting_ID,employee_ID FROM antendee)
```

or (probably better)

```
SELECT m.*
FROM meeting m 
INNER JOIN attendee a a.meeting_ID = m.meeting_ID
INNER JOIN employee e ON e.employee_ID = a.employee_ID
INNER JOIN attendee am ON am.employee_ID = e.manager_ID AND am.meeting_ID = a.meeting_ID
```

Comment: Thank you Andrei. Both are working probably latter is more efficient.

Answer (score 2):

If you just need the names of the meetings, you could use this query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT meeting.meeting_title
FROM
  attendee a1 INNER JOIN employee e ON a1.employee_ID=e.employee_ID
  INNER JOIN attendee a2 ON e.manager_ID=a2.employee_ID
  INNER JOIN meeting ON a1.meeting_ID = meeting.meeting_ID
WHERE
  a1.meeting_ID=a2.meeting_ID
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this, meeting attended by a and b and b is the manager of a

```
SELECT m.*
FROM meeting m 
    JOIN attendee a a.meeting_ID = m.meeting_ID
    JOIN attendee b b.meeting_ID = m.meeting_ID AND a.employee_ID <> b.employee_ID
    JOIN employee e ON e.employee_ID = a.employee_ID AND e.manager_ID = b.employee_ID
```